# Как найти точку соприкосновения точки и ландшафта?

Tags: разработка-игр, 3d

Имеется ландшафт нарисованный в Blender. и имеется точка Vec3.
Задача, не дать упасть точки ниже ландшафта, а сам ландшафт очень бугристый. Как это реализовать?

```
Моя идея такова:
Треугольник ABC и точка P
Перебираю каждый треугольник
{
 Нахожу площадь треугольника ABC только по x И z координате
 Нахожу 3 площади треугольников ABP, ACP, CBP также по x и z координате
 Если сумма этих площадей ABP, ACP, CBP равна площади ABC то точка принадлежит треугольнику иначе не принадлежит.
}
Теперь составляю уравнения плоскости для ABC и получаю y
```

На мой взгляд это много расчетов, висяки будут... Может кто подсказать решение по проще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, обычно ландшафты представляют собой регулярную сетку по горизонтали (размеры ячеек по горизонтали (`x` и `z`) всегда одинаковы, и только по вертикали (`y`) могут отличаться). Тогда найти, в какой клетке  ландшафта находится точка, зная ее координаты и размер ландшафта в "клетках", можно почти мгновенно. Далее можно работать сразу с найденным прямоугольником, или найти, в каком из двух треугольников находится точка и работать с треугольником. Вариантов расчета тут, вообще, несколько. Например, найти координату `y` точки пересечения вертикального луча из позиции точки по `x, z` с плоскостью треугольника. Или можно сложить позиции по `y` всех трех точек треугольника (или 4-х угольника) и разделить на кол-во этих точек (то есть, на 3 или 4), найдя таким образом среднее значение. Что выбрать - зависит от желаемого результата.

Это почти всегда справедливо для ландшафтов, генерируемых из карты высот. Но если ландшафт создан артистом сразу в виде меша - то, вероятно, он не будет представлять собой регулярную сетку. В этом случае можно сделать для него карту высот (например, сгенерировать ее из меша - [это можно в Blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Textures/Maps/Creating_a_Heightmap_from_a_Plane)), грузить ее в игре и использовать информацию из нее для расчета столкновений аналогично описанному выше. Иной вариант - воспользоваться какой-либо физической библиотекой: сделать коллайдер для ландшафта, описать точку физическим телом и пусть все считает физика.

Answer (score 1):

Перебор малого числа треугольников на содержание точки вашим алгоритмом - нормально. Надо сокращать число треугольников которые вы будете перебирать.

Как написал Vladimir, с регулярными террейнами все элементарно.

Для нерегулярных - можно использовать что-то типа квад-дерева (разделить все полигоны террейна на 4 кучи, каждую кучу еще на 4 и т.д., потом при соприкосновении определять в какой оно куче и тестить только полигоны этой кучи).

Или примерно так же - каждому полигону прописать id тайла к которому он относится.

Вариантов оптимизаций много. Напишите сначала общее решение.